# How to respond to a user interaction (slash command) without sending a message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I know there is an InteractionResponseType 2, but it is deprecated, according to the docs. Is there anyway I can respond to a slash command interaction without a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Type 5 did the trick for me.